# TCPDF: Clip text to Cell width

Tags: width, cell, tcpdf

I am generating PDF report using TCPDF's Cell method extensively. Text printed with Cell method spills beyond width specified in method. I want to print only as much part of the text that fits in the specified width but not to spill beyond or wrap to next line. I do not want font stretch strategy.

I searched a lot but could not find a solution. Is there any other method/way to handle this?
(I used setfillcolor(255) to achieve the visual effect. But the text is still there, invisible; gets revealed when you try to select.)

here is my part of code.

```
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255); // only visual effect
    $pdf->Cell(36, 0, "A very big text in the first column, getting printed in 3.6cm width", 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, "Data 1", 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, "Data 2", 0, 0, 'L', true);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you solve that issue using the cell function ?

Answer (score 8):

I have found [an answer here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/forums/forum/435311/topic/2275803) by Nicola Asuni, who is the main TCPDF author. The following code, provided by user *fenstra*, is working for me:

```
// Start clipping.      
$pdf->StartTransform();

// Draw clipping rectangle to match html cell.
$pdf->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, 'CNZ');

// Output html.
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html);

// Stop clipping.
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

As far as I can tell, the clipping rectangle won't consider any padding on the displayed text, so you apply the proper math to Rect's width and height if you need to mimic the behaviour of a MultiCell on this particular.

Comment: Hello Can you solve the cell function instead of the writeHTMLCell function ?

Answer (score 0):

For this one I created it with cell and make function on it to call it globally

```
 * clip Text
     *
     * @param float $w width
     * @param float $h height
     * @param float $x x-axis
     * @param float $y y-axis
     * @param string $str text
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function clipText($w, $h, $x, $y, $str)
    {
        // Start clipping.
        $this->Pdf->StartTransform();
        // Draw clipping rectangle to match cell.
        $this->Pdf->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, 'CNZ');
        // Output text.
        $this->Pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
        $this->Pdf->Cell($w, $h, $str, 0, 0, 'L', 0, 0);
        // Stop clipping.
        $this->Pdf->StopTransform();
    }
```