# TCPDF - Cropping polygons

Tags: pdf, rendering, polygon, tcpdf, vector-graphics

I'm using `TCPDF::Polygon()` to render coastline (land) coordinates from a text file on top of a blue `TCPDF::Rect()`. The text file contains coastlines for the entire world, however by specifying a center latitude and longitude in the map projection, together with some multiplication to get a 'zooming' effect, I manage to display the desired area within the A4 page.

**Problem:**

As you can see by the image the coastlines are drawn all the way to the edge of the document (and beyond). Although most of the coastline coordinates from the text file are 'outside' the document's visible area they are still taking up some hundred kilobytes in the output file.

Is there a nice way to 'crop' the coastline-polygon, so that the coastlines fit nicely inside the blue area and the excess vertecies are completely excluded from the document (not taking up file space)?

[image]

Comment: Are these polygons with both a fill and a stroke? If so, contemplate what clipping would do.

Comment: @rad Thanks for the tip! By clipping using the following method I managed to hide the unwanted polygons: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400490/2667737)

However, the file output size is exactly the same as before, no matter how small the clipping rectangle is. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: That is because you are not *physically* clipping the polygons ... The clipping mask is just added on top of your current outlines. Perhaps you can examine each separate (entire) polygon, test if it has any visible content, and discard when not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

The 'cropping' I was looking for is done using clipping, as suggested by @Rad Lexus:

```
// Start clipping
$pdf->StartTransform();

// Draw clipping rectangle
$pdf->Rect($DOC_MARG, $DOC_MARG, $MAP_W, $MAP_H, 'CNZ');

// -- Draw all polygons here (land areas) --

// Stop clipping
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400490/2667737

To save space in the output file I check every pixel in each polygon (land area) and render only the polygons that has one or more pixels within the bounds of the page - also suggested by @Rad. In the example view in my first post, the size was halved using this method.

Thanks for the help!